# Getting 403 error while integrating react app with wso2

Tags: reactjs, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am integrating react app with wso2. I am using axios to make the fetch request to get the token back.

I have configured the `web.xml.j2` with cors filter

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowOrigin</param-name>
        <param-value>*</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.supportedMethods</param-name>
        <param-value>GET, HEAD, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS, PATCH, PUT</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.exposedHeaders</param-name>
        <param-value>Location</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

Apart from that I have also set `deployment.toml` file with CORS exception

```
[cors]
allow_generic_http_requests = true
allow_any_origin = false
allowed_origins = [
    "http://localhost:3000"
]
allow_subdomains = false
supported_methods = [
    "GET",
    "POST",
    "HEAD",
    "OPTIONS"
]
support_any_header = true
supported_headers = []
exposed_headers = []
supports_credentials = true
max_age = 3600
tag_requests = false
```

After doing all of this I still get the error as below

```json
TOKEN REQUEST ERROR 

{
    "data": "Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) Filter: CORS origin denied: http://localhost:3000\n",
    "status": 403,
    "statusText": "",
    "headers": {
        "content-length": "87",
```

Please advice.

I am following the tutorial [here](https://medium.com/identity-beyond-borders/oauth-2-0-authorization-code-flow-react-spa-demo-using-wso2-identity-server-5829b890a6d4)

Comment: What is your WSO2 IS version ?

Comment: The version is 5.11.0

Comment: You don't need to configure web.xml.j2 for cors configurations in IS-5.11.0 onwards. CORS configurations should be done via deployment.toml

Comment: So remove the web.xml.j2 file changes and go ahead with deployment.toml changes you have added. Even if you couldn't get it working, set `allow_any_origin` to true and try the folow to verify that cors configs are getting into action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CORS configurations has to be made from deployment.toml in IS 5.11.0 and it is not required to update web.xml (or j2). Therefore, you can revert the changes done in j2 template and continue using the config defined in deployment.toml.

You can refer to the [documentation](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.11.0/learn/cors/) for more information.